# how to give a href inside the button tag in html

Tags: javascript, html

i need to open two links when a button is clicked in the html page. I figured it as by calling onclick function and creating anchor tag using createElement in Javascript. But how to include another link?? Is there a way to give a href in button tag??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply do that with javascript

```
window.open(url1);
window.open(url2);
```

And if you want to open one of that links in curren window you can replace window.open by this

```
window.location = url1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  <input type="button" value="Double Clicker"  onclick="window.open(&quot;http://www.google.com/&quot;); window.open(&quot;http://www.youtube.com/&quot;);" />
```

see [this link](http://www.bloggersentral.com/2009/11/opening-multiple-links-in-single-click.html) for further information,

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a javascript event to make the page go somewhere

```
<input type="button" name="button1" value="Go To Url" onClick="window.navigate('URL')">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
location.href=" ";`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to see what the location object can do => http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp
You should be able to load two tab.

Answer (score 0):

why dont u use bootstrap

```
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">
```

It displays a button with link going to what is mentioned in href